# Java implementation for Android AAPT?

Tags: java, android, apk, aapt

Is there java implementation for Android AAPT ? Any other tools? I need AAPT tool without CPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no java implementation of AAPT/AAPT2. However, you can call it from java similarly to the way Android Gradle Plugin does. If it's something relatively simple that you want to achieve, perhaps this [article](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077513/learn-java/java-tip-17--integrating-java-with-c--.html) could be helpful. Otherwise, have a look at the AGP sources.